# To store and retrieve data in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm very new to this.
In my application I have an option for sign up.
After successful sign up, the username, email and password should be saved on device as login data for later authentication. Is it possible? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial for using `NSUserDefaults`: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/